# Will WPA or WEP BT crackers perform well on Galaxy Tab?

Tags: wifi, backtrack, tablet

I checked some videos on YouTube, and it talks about how to install BT on different Linux tablets, like the Galaxy Tab and really wonder if `reaver`, `aircrack` or whatever other tools would work just fine or lets say detecting the wireless adapter (`wlanXX`) embedded in the tablet as a normal WiFi device to start the work? If yes, will I expect the same performance as with Laptops and PC's? Because I'm really thinking of buying one but need to make sure that it does the necessary work first.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer as im 90% sure however note that i have no personal experiance.

First off, a weak multi core laptop processor will far out process a tablet. Secondly using a dedicated video with CUDA support to help with the cracking will DRAMATICALLY increase the speed (more than double the speed of the CPU)

With that said i would HIGHLY doubt that a tablet would even be half the speed of a cheap laptop.

PS: buying a cheap desktop computer for cracking (spending same money as laptop) would even be better. Cheap ATI video cards will do wonders in cracking

Comment: Good answer but bad news for me. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem would be putting the tablet in monitor mode, to actually listen to packets. Does the module for galaxy tab wireless adapter supports it ( I believe that it doesn't and wont in near future).

For cracking the password with PC or GPU, its quite quick on WEP side, so it shouldn't be a problem for a tablet too ( assuming one has the needed data to crack it, for which you need atleast monitor mode, preferably one that can inject packets).

On the other hand WPA is still almost impossible to crack on a standard workstation, if the password is decent, so no hopes there.